# Why the thread behaves this way in my example?

Tags: java, android, handler

Can someone explain to me 2 things about the thread code that I finally made almost working the way it should. I want to do a periodic task in the background every x seconds and be able to stop and start it at will.  I coded that based on the examples I found, but I'm not sure if I made it in the right way. For the purpose of debugging, the task is displaying a time with custom showTime().

```
public class LoopExampleActivity extends Activity {

    TextView Napis, Napis2;
    Button button1,button_start,button_stop;
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Boolean tread1_running = true;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Napis = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        Napis2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button_stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_stop);
        button_start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_start);


        button_stop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick (View v) {
                tread1_running = false;
                                }
            });
        button_start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick (View v) {
                tread1_running = true;


                                }
            });

        thread.start();


    }// endof  onCreate


    final Runnable r = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run() 
        {

            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            showTime(Napis2);

        }
    };

    Thread thread = new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while(tread1_running) {
                    sleep(1000);
                    handler.post(r);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

}
```

Now the questions are: 
1)Will my thread quit forever if I stop it with the stop button?

2)Why can't I start it again with the start_button? If I add the tread.start() in a button, will it crash?

3) I tried a second version when I let the thread run and put a condition into the handler. The only way I can get it to work is to loop conditionaly in the handler by adding an

```
if (thread1_running) {
                handler.postDelayed(this, 2000);
                showTime(Napis2);
            }
```

And changing the condition in a thread start to

```
 while (true)
```

but then I have an open thread that is running all the time and I start and stop it in a handler, and it posts more and more handlers.

So, finally I get to the point it looks like that:

```
final Runnable r = new Runnable()
{
    public void run() 
    {

        if (thread1_running) handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            showTime(Napis2);

    }
};

Thread thread = new Thread()
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while(true) {
                sleep(1000);
                if (thread1_running) handler.post(r);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

Is the proper way to do that is to start and stop a whole thread? Or that is the best way?

Answer (score 0):

Threads a described by a [state machine](http://www.science.uva.nl/ict/ossdocs/java/tutorial/java/threads/states.html) in java.

When a thread get outs of its run method, it enters in the stopped state and can't be restarted.

You should always stop a thread by getting it out of its run method as you do, it s the proper way to do it.

If you want to "restart the thread", start a new instance of your thread class.

You should better encapsulate your thread and its running field. It should be inside your thread class and the class should offer a public method to swich the boolean. No one cares about your datastructure, hide them. :)

You should consider using runOnUIThread for your runnable, its much easier to use than handlers.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve something like that would be, in my humble opinion, to `postDelayed(Runnable, long)`.

You could do something like this. Class definition:

```
private Handler mMessageHandler = new Handler();

private Runnable mUpdaterRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            doStuff();
            showTime(Napis2);
            mMessageHandler.postDelayed(mUpdaterRunnable, 1000);
        }
};
```

And control true run/stop like this:

To start:

```
mMessageHandler.postDelayed(mUpdaterRunnable, 1000);
```

And to stop:

```
mMessageHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdaterRunnable);
```

It's much much simpler, in my humble opinion.

Comment: I think I need a separate tread as I need  to put in mUpdaterRunnable a call to the server over the network that can be quite slow (up to 1s) and dont want to make my app slugish.

Comment: ..... and I just tested that code (without the thread) and it crashes on the first mMessageHandler.postDelayed(mUpdaterRunnable, 1000); that I do in my application onCreate().

Comment: Update your question (append at the end) your current code (just the minimum, please) and your log cat error lines. The current situation is not clear to me.

Comment: Since first asked my problem developed into this question that describes it better i hope http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523784/why-second-thread-halts-execution-of-the-first-one