# Android - Why second thread halts execution of the first one?

Tags: android, multithreading

I have an app that runs 2 threads in loops. 1st one is updating a graph in 1s interval and the second one is updating another graph at 60s interval.  The second task is taking a long time since it is quering some server in the internet 3 times that might not always be available and even if it is it will take up to 5-7s to execute.

What is happening is when I launch the second thread it will pause execution of the first one and that is not what I want, I wish both run concurrently. Here in the Youtube video you can see the results of the app running. http://youtu.be/l7K5zSWzlxI
"thread_updater1s" is running a  green graph, large readout, and a timer in the corner so you clearly see it stalls for 11 seconds.

1)First of all why is that happening? how to fix it?

2)I'm aware that I might not launch the threads properly at all. I had hard time understanding how to make something to run in a interval loop in Java and my code worked fine for one graph/tread. Now when I have 2 loops in separate threads I don't know why they are not executing concurrently.

Here is the code:

```
public class LoopExampleActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    thread_updater1s.start();
    thread_updater2.start();
}// end of onCreate

final Runnable r1s = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        do_1s_updates(); // those are very quick http calls to the local API server 
    }                    // to get data nessessary for some plot.
                        // They have 1s timeout as well but rarely timeout
};

final Runnable r2 = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        do_large_updates(); //This makes 7 long call over the Internet to the slow https
                            //server once every 60s. Has 10s timeout and sometimes takes as much as
                            //7s to execute
        }
};

Thread thread_updater1s = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                handler.post(r1s);
                sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

Thread thread_updater2 = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                handler2.post(r2);
                sleep(60000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

}

PS. please be forgiving and informative I only code Java for 15 days so far with absolutely no prior experince or lesson.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the http requests in the threads (not the posted runnables). Then, when you have the data downloaded, you create a runnable with that data that will update the graph and post that runnable to be executed by the UI thread. Here is an example:

```
public class LoopExampleActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    thread_updater1s.start();
    thread_updater2.start();
}// end of onCreate

Thread thread_updater1s = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                final Object data = getDataFromServer1();
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        updateGraph1(data);
                    }
                );
                sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

Thread thread_updater2 = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                final Object data = getDataFromServer2();
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        updateGraph2(data);
                    }
                );
                sleep(60000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

Obviously, change that final Object data by the appropriate class that represents your data downloaded.

Comment: Thakanks for the idea, that aproach requires me to separate getting the data from the posting it to the graph, this will be a massive redesign of the app. Is there a way to execute my runnables as they are right now, just in the background?

Comment: Done, It was actually not that difficult, just you have to eliminate all the calls to the UI in the treads as it is forbiden to call them from the Threads, for some reason, so no more textview's for exception debug :) Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

handler.post pushes the runnable onto the main (UI) thread's message queue for execution on the main thread.

So what you're doing is every sleep interval, you're sending a message to the main thread to run the function. Clearly, the main thread can't run 2 things at once, so that's why one runnable is delayed for the next one.

You probably want to do the work of the runnable in the separate threads - why did you start using a handler? What happens if you call `do_1s_updates` and `do_large_updates` directly instead of through the handler & runnable?

Comment: Thanks, that is an eye opener! Didn't know that handlers post to main UI. But how can I make a loop out of the threads alone can I do thread_updater1s.post() on the end to make a loop out of it?

Comment: I used handler as that was a first example that I found working on a web to make a loop, that i can pause easily. I see there are also HandlerThread is that what i need, so I would not have to change much im my app?